# Css transform rotate for safari

Tags: html, css, macos, animation, safari

Hi I am developing a corporate website and while it works well for almost all browsers, I can't seem to get it properly working on safari.
The cards on the top pages are supposed to be rotating but on safari it seems the transformation is being applied to the whole HTML page.

[Actual top page here](http://feelsjapan.main.jp/c-trust9_23/)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: This looks exactly the same on both browsers.